# I am Trying To Remove listing.php?category=Pharmaceutical But Uable to do with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL with these parameters `listing.php?category=Pharmaceutical`
but I want it like

```
/category=Pharmaceutical
```

I am Using .htaccess code here

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)*$ ./listing.php?category==$1
```

But this is Not Working, Is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?category=123

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+).php\?category=([^&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+).php\?category=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)(/[^/]+)?/?$ $1.php?category=$2 [L,QSA]